# Node [Affinity/AntiAffinity ] along with Pod [Affinity/AntiAffinity]

Tags: kubernetes, affinity

I have a pod that has both node affinity and pod affinity. could some help me understand how would things behave in such a scenario?

Node 1:

```
   label: 
        schedule-on : gpu
```

Node 2:

```
   label: 
        schedule-on : gpu
```

Node 3:

```
   label: 
        schedule-on : non-gpu
```

Manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: test
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:  
        app.kubernetes.io/name: test
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: schedule-on
                operator: In
                values:
                - gpu
        podAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
                operator: In
                values:
                - test
            topologyKey: schedule-on
```

the output of the above is:
Pods are getting scheduled on a different node [node1,node2]

ideal output: Pod needs to be scheduled on the same node [node1]

Here is my finding.

Finding 1: I believe node affinity is taking  precedence  and pod affinity is getting ignored

Comment: Please upload ```kubectl get nodes --show-labels``` output as well

Comment: I noticed your answer - to confirm - do you need any more help here?

Answer (score 1):

It's the union of node affinity and pod affinity. since both the pod has the same topology key domain . hence making them in the same colocation the pods can get scheduled in different nodes but in same colocation .

When matching the topology key and placing the pod. Value of the key is also considered

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some definitions to your answer.

First of all, from [this article](https://www.howtoforge.com/use-node-affinity-in-kubernetes/):

> ***Node affinity*** is a set of rules. It is used by the scheduler to decide where a pod can be placed in the cluster. The rules are defined using labels on nodes and label selectors specified in pods definition. Node affinity allows a pod to specify an affinity towards a group of nodes it can be scheduled on.

And from [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/admin_guide/scheduling/pod_affinity.html):

> ***Pod affinity*** can tell the scheduler to locate a new pod on the same node as other pods if the label selector on the new pod matches the label on the current pod.

In your scenario: as you wrote - both pods have the same topology key domain. This fact makes them in the same colocation, so the pods can get scheduled in different nodes but in same colocation.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#:%7E:text=reduce%20the%20skew.-,topologyKey,-is%20the%20key) are also some words about `topologyKey`:

> ***TopologyKey***  is the key of node labels. If two Nodes are labelled with this key and have identical values for that label, the scheduler treats both Nodes as being in the same topology. The scheduler tries to place a balanced number of Pods into each topology domain.